# How to make a custom selection on excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, spreadsheet

Is it possible to make a custom selection on a spreadsheet and in particular on excel ?
If yes, how to do it ?

(for example, I would like to select one cell on 3 among a column
or select only the cells which contain a certain value
or 1 line on 2)

**EDIT** I have a lot of value, more than 100 lines, so selecting with CTRL is not easy.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking.  Can you add an example to your question?  mock up something simple or add a link to a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a bunch of non-continuous cells you hold down CTRL and left click/drag the mouse.

It also sounds like English is not your first language so you may need to have someone proof read your question to see if it makes sense.

Comment: I have a lot of value, more than 100 lines, so selecting with CTRL is not easy. it is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to do?  Excel can't read your mind so how else will Excel know what cells you want to select?